# How do I remove duplicate objects in array and count the duplicate occurrence using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var arr = [{
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.1",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.2",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.3",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, 
...
```

I have managed to remove duplicate objects but how do I count the occurrence of the duplicates?

The idea is if the object in the array is the same, count it. The output should add a `count` property to the each of the objects and the value of the `count` property, should be its occurrence.

```
const result = {
  data: arr
}

result.data = result.data.filter((result, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.bldg_name === result.bldg_name && t.psa_brgy === result.psa_brgy && t.bldg_type === result.bldg_type && t.hazard_level === result.hazard_level)

  )
)
console.log(result)
```

The [JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/fd6gvvu4/32/).

Comment: *"The JSFiddle is here."* Please use the **on-site** Stack Snippets for live examples (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Should be like `"bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH","count: <number of occurrence>"`

Comment: First, you must define what is DUPLICATE due to in your example gid is different

Comment: the `gid` can be ignored..if the other properties are the same, the object is considered as DUPLICATE.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a solution.

```js
var arr = [{
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.1",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.2",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.3",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.4",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.5",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.6",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.7",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.8",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.9",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.10",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.11",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.12",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.13",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.14",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.15",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.16",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.17",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.18",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.19",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.20",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.21",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.22",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.23",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.24",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.25",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.26",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.27",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.28",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.29",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.30",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.31",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.32",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.33",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.34",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Obrero Pob. (Bgy. 18)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.35",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.36",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.37",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.38",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.39",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.40",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.41",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.42",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.43",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.44",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.45",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.46",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.47",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.48",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.49",
  "bldg_name": "San Miguel",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Factory",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.50",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Port Poyohon Pob. (Bgy. 17 - New Asia)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.51",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.52",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.53",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.54",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.55",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.56",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Ong Yiu Pob. (Bgy. 16)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.57",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Leon Kilat Pob. (Bgy. 13)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.58",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Leon Kilat Pob. (Bgy. 13)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.59",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Leon Kilat Pob. (Bgy. 13)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.60",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.61",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.62",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Doongan",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "LOW"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.63",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Bading Pob. (Bgy. 22)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "LOW"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.64",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Doongan",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "LOW"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.65",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Doongan",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "LOW"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.66",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Doongan",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "LOW"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.67",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Agao Pob. (Bgy. 3)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.68",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Agao Pob. (Bgy. 3)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.69",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.70",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Agao Pob. (Bgy. 3)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.71",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Agao Pob. (Bgy. 3)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.72",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.73",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.74",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.75",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.76",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.77",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.78",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.79",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.80",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.81",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.82",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.83",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.84",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.85",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.86",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.87",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.88",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.89",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.90",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.91",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.92",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.93",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.94",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.95",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.96",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.97",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "MEDIUM"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.98",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.99",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.100",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.101",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.102",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.103",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.104",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "Golden Ribbon Pob. (Bgy. 2)",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.105",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "San Vicente",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.106",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "San Vicente",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}, {
  "gid": "affected_bxu_nrt.107",
  "bldg_name": "Unknown",
  "psa_brgy": "San Vicente",
  "bldg_type": "Residential",
  "hazard_level": "HIGH"
}];

const result = {
  data: arr
}

function compare(obj1, obj2) {
  let equal = false;

  Object.keys(obj1).every((e) => {    
    if (e === 'gid' || e === 'count') { return true; }
    equal = obj1[e] === obj2[e];
    return equal;
  });

  return equal;
}

const r = arr.reduce(function (rv, x) {    
  let el = rv.find(function (e) {
     if (compare(e, x)) { return e; }
    });
    if (el) {
     if (el.count) { el.count++; }
      else { el.count = 1; }
    } else {
     rv.push(x);
    }
    return rv;
}, []);

console.log(r)
```